# Can I run 12 vdc power cord from an indoor transformer (plugged into an interior 120vac outlet) through an outside wall to power a security camera?

Tags: electrical

The location where I want to install my outdoor security camera is not near an exterior outlet, and besides, I would rather not have cords strung around the house.   It is not solar nor PoE.  The camera is powered by a 12VDC transformer which will plug into a 120VAC outlet.  I would like to plug the transformer into an interior outlet, and run the 12VDC cord through the wall in the vicinity of the camera.  Is my plan safe and compliant?

Comment: Are there any markings on the outside of the 12V cable from the transformer?

Comment: Yes, can you provide the markings off said low-voltage cable?

Comment: I would say yes.   Basically, with any low voltage system, there isn't any danger from the crazy bone-headed things guys do so there aren't any standards or requirements....(as far as I know).

Comment: Most important is that the transformer provide good isolation from the AC mains. Some "wall wart" power supplies, particularly high-frequency switching supplies, have excessive leakage. A standard "bell" transformer, mounted to a grounded metal enclosure should be safe in this use.

Comment: While the answer may be yes, there is a practical approach.  Buy white low voltage wire that is rated for this.  Run that from near the camera to near the wall socket.  Cut the PSU cable in half and splice it to the white wire at each location.  This solves several problems: 1) The transformer's wire may not reach from the camera location outside to a receptacle inside 2) The transformer's DC plug will need a larger hole to run through walls than just a wire 3) Black wire run along walls and baseboards doesn't look as good as white.

Answer (score 0):

The insulation on the cable **should** be rated & marked something like "CL2" for a low voltage through-wall (concealed) application. It might be, it might not be.

One approach would be to run a short section of conduit through the wall, which minimizes the exposure of the cable itself to damage or fire.

Use (electrical) duct seal putty to keep air and insects from moving through the conduit.